# Combine results of two queries postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, postgresql-9.1

I have two queries like this:

```
SELECT project_id, user_ip, count(*) AS Count 
FROM "user" 
WHERE user_ip IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY user_ip, project_id;

SELECT project_id, user_id, count(*) AS Count 
FROM "user" 
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY user_id, project_id;
```

They are all the same except that one returns the users based on IP and other on ID.

Users can have only one of this, so basically if the `user_ip`  is `Null` then `user_id` will have value and the opposite  if `user_id`  is `Null`
then `user_ip` will have value.

So all I want is to make those query one query.

The first query gives this:

```
project_id | user_ip | Count            
  1        | 1.2.3.4 | 40        
  2        | 1.2.3.5 | 25    
  3        | 1.2.3.6 | 9          
  4        | 1.2.3.7 | 7
```

The second gives this:

```
project_id | user_id | Count            
  1        |  1234   | 100        
  2        |  4567   | 50    
  3        |  4321   | 49
```

So I want to make only one query that will return this:

```
project_id | user_id | user_ip | Count            
  1        |  1234   |         | 100 
  1        |         | 1.2.3.4 | 40       
  2        |  4567   |         | 50
  2        |         | 1.2.3.5 | 25     
  3        |  4321   |         | 49 
  3        |         | 1.2.3.6 | 9          
  4        |         | 1.2.3.7 | 7
```

I tried to do a left join also I tried to do it with Union but I get ERROR:  `UNION types text and integer cannot be matched`

```
SELECT project_id, user_ip, count(*) AS Count 
FROM "user" 
WHERE user_ip IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY user_ip, project_id  
UNION 
SELECT project_id, user_id, count(*) AS Count 
FROM "user" 
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL GROUP 
BY user_id, project_id;
```

Can someone help me to achieve the results that I want? What can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `NULL as user_id/ip` in the projection, in the SELECT clause.

```
SELECT project_id, NULL as user_id, user_ip, count(*) AS Count ...
union
SELECT project_id, user_id, NULL as user_ip, count(*) AS Count
```

---

Alternatively, instead union, try `group by project_id, user_id, user_ip`, that should work too. This might be even faster.

```
SELECT project_id, user_id, user_ip, count(*) AS Count 
FROM "user" 
GROUP BY project_id, user_id, user_ip;
```

Comment: I tried with group like this `SELECT project_id, user_ip, count(user_ip) AS Count_ip, count(user_id) as count_id FROM "user" WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL OR user_ip IS NOT NULL GROUP BY user_id, project_id, user_ip;` but I couldn't make it work because it gives me wrong results

Comment: maybe try with just a single count(*). Also is the WHERE clause is not needed unless there is a case where both user_id and ip are NULL. I'll update the answer with a full query

Answer (score 3):

Queries of union need to have same number and type of all columns. Try this:

```
SELECT project_id, user_ip, null as user_id, count(*) AS Count FROM "user" WHERE user_ip IS NOT NULL GROUP BY user_ip, project_id  
UNION 
SELECT project_id, null as user_ip, user_id, count(*) AS Count FROM "user" WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY user_id, project_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use `union all`.  Second, convert the values to text ... one is a number and the other a string:

```
SELECT project_id, user_ip::text, count(*) AS Count 
FROM "user" 
WHERE user_ip IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY user_ip, project_id  
UNION ALL
SELECT project_id, user_id::text, count(*) AS Count 
FROM "user" 
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY user_id, project_id;
```

You can also write this using `GROUPING SETS` in Postgres 9.5+:

```
SELECT project_id, COALESCE(user_ip::text, user_id::text),
       count(*) AS Count 
FROM "user" 
WHERE user_ip IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((project_id, user_ip), (project_id, user_id))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I get this : `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SETS"`

Comment: @Egjupss . . . My bad.  That is only available in Postgres 9.5+.

Answer (score 0):

[Grouping sets](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS) (9.5+)

```
select *
from (
    select project_id, user_id, user_ip, count(*)
    from "user"
    group by grouping sets ((project_id, user_id), (project_id, user_ip))
) s
where user_id is not null or user_ip is not null
```